# No wireless in sony vaio laptop

Tags: wireless

I have a sony vaio laptop with ubuntu installed.  How can I turn my wireless on?  In windows I can use fn+f5 keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following command:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

I had the same problem and solved it. OR use

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```